# How to use GROUP BY to calculate intervals

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

please consider this image:

[image]

I have a table like this:

```
 Age              Active            Men/Women
 -------------------------------------------------
```

I want to write a query that calulate `Count` of every age intervals for men and women.I don't know How I can use `GROUP BY` and intervals.

in my reports in left side of above image I want to calculate `UnActive` rows.How I can merge this to query to one query?

thanks

Comment: can you paste your table data with structure

Comment: Presentation of data is different to how the data comes from the database. What you have above is quite contrived

Comment: how is the `Total` of `800` and `200` = `500`? and where does `417.5` come from?? do you mean `Average` instead of `Total`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    Active.State,
    Age.Base, Age.Base+4,
    COUNT(*) AS TotalCount,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN T.[Men/Women] = 'man' THEN 1 END) AS ManCount,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN T.[Men/Women] = 'woman' THEN 1 END) AS WomanCount
FROM
    (
    VALUES (10),(15),(20),(25),(30),(35),(40) /*.. add the rest */,(90),(95)
    ) AS Age(base)
    CROSS JOIN
    (
    VALUES (0), (1)
    ) AS Active(State)
    LEFT JOIN
    MyTable T ON T.Age BETWEEN Age.Base AND Age.Base+4 AND T.Active = Active.State
GROUP BY
    Active.State,
    Age.Base, Age.Base+4;
```

After this, you can format it how you want

Edited to generate empty ranges

Comment: Thanks @gbn, your code has 2 problem.first error in `AS` in `GROUP BY` clause.second when I ran your code with @Seph data I got 2 rows for 30-34.

Comment: Thanks @gbn.there is another problem.In My report when an interval has not value I should show zero for columns.How I can change your query to group all Intervals?Many thanks

Comment: @Rozhin: added. You may need to play with the GROUP BY to get what you want

Answer (score 1):

You can GROUP BY on age interval CASEs:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AGE_COUNT,
    CASE WHEN AGE BETWEEN 15 AND 19 THEN 'Age 15-19'
         WHEN AGE BETWEEN 20 AND 24 THEN 'Age 20-24'
         ELSE 'Other'
    END AGE_INTERVAL
FROM
    YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY
    CASE WHEN AGE BETWEEN 15 AND 19 THEN 'Age 15-19'
         WHEN AGE BETWEEN 20 AND 24 THEN 'Age 20-24'
         ELSE 'Other'
    END
```

Comment: I ran your query with @Seph data but it just raturns 2 rows `Age 20-24---------Other`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN [Men/Women] = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Men,
 SUM(CASE WHEN [Men/Women] = 'W' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Women,
 COUNT(*) as Total,
 CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN 10 AND 14 THEN 'Age 10-14'
    WHEN Age BETWEEN 15 AND 19 THEN 'Age 15-19'
    WHEN Age BETWEEN 20 AND 24 THEN 'Age 20-24'
    ELSE 'Old'
END Age
FROM MyTable
WHERE Active = 1
GROUP BY     CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN 10 AND 14 THEN 'Age 10-14'
    WHEN Age BETWEEN 15 AND 19 THEN 'Age 15-19'
    WHEN Age BETWEEN 20 AND 24 THEN 'Age 20-24'
    ELSE 'Old'
END
```

Comment: I ran your query with @Seph data but it just raturns 2 rows `Age 20-24 -----Old`

Answer (score 1):

You can actually expand on from what Andrea provided...

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN YT.AGE BETWEEN 15 AND 19 THEN 'Age 15-19'
         WHEN YT.AGE BETWEEN 20 AND 24 THEN 'Age 20-24'
         ELSE 'Other'
    END AGE_INTERVAL,
    SUM( CASE WHEN YT.Active THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as ActiveCount,
    SUM( CASE WHEN YT.Gender = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as MaleCount,
    SUM( CASE WHEN YT.Gender = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as FemaleCount,
    COUNT(*) AgeGroupCount
FROM
    YourTable YT
GROUP BY
   Age_Interval
```

Comment: thanks @DRapp.I ran your I got this error: `Invalid column name 'Age_Interval'.`

Comment: @Rozhin, it might be a SQL-Server thing vs MySQL... You might have to copy the entire case/when used to create the Age_Interval column, just leave of the "AGE_INTERVAL" part label in the group by section

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned this is trying to report on a way that is not the same as your data at all.

But I think the best way achieve this within SQL is to create a scalar function (props to @gbn for the min/max age range logic):

```
CREATE FUNCTION usvf_calculate_age_bracket
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @age INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN CAST(@age/5*5 AS VARCHAR(20)) + '-' + CAST(@age/5*5+4 AS VARCHAR(20))
END
GO
```

Then in your query you can do:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'F' THEN active ELSE 0 END) AS [Women],
    SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'M' THEN active ELSE 0 END) AS [Men], 
    SUM(CAST(active AS int)) AS [Total],
    'Age ' + dbo.usvf_calculate_age_bracket(age) AS [Age]
FROM myTable
GROUP BY dbo.usvf_calculate_age_bracket(age)
```

My test code:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
age int,
active bit,
gender char(1)

)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES (25, 1, 'M'),(32, 0, 'F'),(21, 1, 'M'),(22, 1, 'F'),(28, 1, 'F'),(32, 0, 'M'), (23, 1, 'M'),(42, 0, 'F'),(29, 1, 'M'),(29, 1, 'F'),(28, 1, 'F'),(32, 1, 'M')

SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'F' THEN active ELSE 0 END) AS [Women],
SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'M' THEN active ELSE 0 END) AS [Men], 
SUM(CAST(active AS int)) AS [Total],
'Age ' + dbo.usvf_calculate_age_bracket(age) AS [Age] FROM @T
GROUP BY dbo.usvf_calculate_age_bracket(age)
```

Results:

```
Women Men Total Age
1    2    3     Age 20-24
3    2    5     Age 25-29
0    1    1     Age 30-34
0    0    0     Age 40-44
```

Which seems to be close to what you want, and it isn't an overly complicated SQL query to achieve this. (except I can't work out your 'total' column)